# Does Javascript have a built in way to execute existing events after a listener is added?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, keyboard-events

In Javascript I do this

```
window.addEventListener("aaa", event => {
    alert("hddi");
});

window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("aaa", {detail:1}));
```

which works, but is there a minimalistic way that I can dispatch events and have it all queue up, then attach the listener, and have it execute all events in a queue (FIFO), like this:

```
window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("aaa", {detail:1}));
window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("aaa", {detail:1}));
window.dispatchEvent(new CustomEvent("aaa", {detail:1}));
window.addEventListener("aaa", event => {
    alert("hddi");  // alerts 3 times
});
```

I'm looking to avoid any libraries and just minimize on custom code. Is there a native way to do this even?

Comment: I don't think there is a native way to handle this. I think you would have to implement some kind of custom queuing mechanism to handle this.

Comment: What higher level problem are you trying to solve?

Answer (score 0):

JavaScript **dispatches events to the attached event handlers immediately** when those events are fired. I do not know of a native way to have a bunch of events queued up, attach a handler, and then have it process the queue.

What you are looking for is a **simple queue**, plus a handler function for processing each item:

```js
var aaa_queue = [];

aaa_queue.push({ detail: 1 });
aaa_queue.push({ detail: 2 });
aaa_queue.push({ detail: 3 });

var aaa_handler = function(obj) {
  console.log(["Now handling:", obj]);
};

var process_queue = function(queue, handler) {
  while(queue.length > 0) {
    handler(queue.shift());   // shift() removes and returns the first item
  }
};

process_queue(aaa_queue, aaa_handler);
```